# Probability of nonsingular matrix over finite ring

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $p|q$. Let $m $ and $n$ be integer$(m>n)$.

Consider a ring $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Z_q$.(modulus $p$, modulus $q$ ,respectively)

Let R be a ring and $A \in Mat_{m \times n}(R)$. If $rankA = n$,  A is called "nonsingular".

I want to compare Pr[$A\in Mat_{m \times n}(Z_p)$ is nonsingular] to Pr[$A\in Mat_{m \times n}(Z_q)$ is nonsingular]. 
Since I can't compute the Probability of $Z_q$ case, I don't know which one is larger than the other one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't well-defined since you didn't specify a distribution. I'll assume that you intended to imply that the matrix elements are independently uniformly drawn from the respective rings.

You can reduce any matrix over $\mathbb Z_q$ to a matrix over $\mathbb Z_p$ by taking the elements modulo $p$; this doesn't increase its rank, and applying it to a matrix from the above distribution again yields a matrix from the corresponding distribution. Thus the probability that a matrix over $\mathbb Z_p$ is singular is at least the probability that a matrix over $\mathbb Z_q$ is singular. Since it's straightforward to exhibit an example of a matrix that's non-singular over $\mathbb Z_q$ but singular when reduced to $\mathbb Z_p$, the probability that a matrix over $\mathbb Z_p$ is singular is in fact greater than the probability that a matrix over $\mathbb Z_q$ is singular.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't know why modulus does not affect its rank.

Comment: @swain: I said the opposite: That it's straightforward to exhibit an example where it does affect the rank.

Comment: Then the rank of matrix over Z_q is smaller than rank of the matrix over Z_p, right? I'm very confused. Sorry

Comment: @swain: No, it's *not* smaller.